# How to migrate tokens from one project to another in Google console

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-console-developer

We are having one Google console project for all our apps using Google Calendar now but we need to migrate token to another new project as the API quota is getting exceeded frequently.

So my question is, how can OAuth tokens be migrated between two client IDs in the same Google console account?

For example, suppose an OAuth token is created with a web client Id "A" in a project "Test1". How can this be migrated to be used with a web client Id "B" in project "Test2"? Both Test1 and Test2 will be in same Google account.

Comment: AFAIK,it cannot be done as described above. If you are having trouble with your current API quota, why not try requesting for a higher one? Look at the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGdqD.png) for guidance

Comment: We have increased the quota limit after raising Google higher quota form. But with our customer base increasing, it won't be long before this quota is also exceeded. So if there is any way to migrate the tokens, it will be awesome!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible since the `clientID` and `client secret` is tied up to a specific project (you would run into permission error). I think one workaround would be asking a high quota request while fixing your code. Another suggestion would be creating a `projectID` for a specific target separate users from mobile to web. If you have done all of this and still hits the API quota limit then the only option would be requesting for a higher one, right?